# reading a string with new line and comma into a list wit

Tags: python, string

I have a string as shown below that correspond to date, agency, drivers license and car.

```
st = '2020-09-12, Budget, DF8576, Ford,\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143266, Toyota, \n ..'
```

[image]

I want to split by new line (\n) first and then by comma and read into a list like below

```
lst = [['2020-09-12', 'Budget', 'DF8576', 'Ford'],
       ['2020-04-22', 'Avis', 'D143266', 'Toyota'],
        :
        ]
```

I tried this code below:

```
  st.split('\n')
```

It gives:

```
['2020-09-12, Budget, DF8576, Ford,\\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143266,..]
```

I am not sure why it is giving `\\n` when I want to split by new line first and then by comma.

Can you please help?

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Right now the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: *and then by comma* - add that part into input and expected output

Comment: Also your example is incossitent, e.g. `,\n`, then `, \n`. Is that really the case? also, why there is trailing comma before the new line?

Comment: If you're getting that result, the string contains literal `\n`, not newlines.

Comment: That would happen if you used a raw string: `st = r'2020-09-12, Budget, DF8576, Ford,\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143266, Toyota, \n ..'`

Comment: How are you actually getting the original string? Is it coming from the user, a file, or is it really a literal like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with specific pattern:

```
import re

st = '2020-09-12, Budget, DF8576, Ford,\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143266, Toyota, \n ..'
lst = [a.strip().split(',') for a in re.split(r',\s*\n', st)]
print(lst)
```

---

```
[['2020-09-12', 'Budget', 'DF8576', 'Ford'], ['2020-04-22', 'Avis', 'D143266', 'Toyota'], ['..']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following with `replace()`, `split()` and `list comprehension`:

```
st = '2020-09-12, Budget, DF8576, Ford,\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143266, Toyota, \n ..'
st = st.replace(' ', '') # Get rid of white space
st = st.split('\n')
result = [i.split(',')[:-1] for i in st][:-1] # [:-1] because you don't want the empty string before \n
```

results holds:

```
[['2020-09-12', 'Budget', 'DF8576', 'Ford'], ['2020-04-22', 'Avis', 'D143266', 'Toyota']]
```